# asp.net core 2.0 - Claims and policy based Authorization

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization, claims-based-identity

I am using cookie authentication with claims identity. authentication works fine but authorization fails.

here am storing claims information if login credentials match.

```
 var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, _user[0].UserName.ToString()));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, _user[0].UserRole));
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, _user[0].UserEmail)); 
 HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));
```

here is the authorization setup in startup.cs configurationServices method

```
 services.AddMvc();
 services.AddAuthorization(options => {
                options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("Admin"));
                options.AddPolicy("User", policy => policy.RequireClaim("User"));

            });
```

and the controller

```
 [Authorize(Policy = "Admin")]
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
//
    }
```

This authorization redirects to me to access denied page although admin logs in with role. What are the problems here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the claim type and what value it should have

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy =>
        {
            policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin");
        });
     options.AddPolicy("User", policy =>
        {
            policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User");
        });
});
```

Comment: thanks ,,I changed to what you said, now admin can access it .user role should have denied access . but user role can also access it now

Comment: @e2e can you put a breakpoint in your controller's Action somewhere and explore the `User` property to ensure it's got the role claim you're expecting?

Comment: Hey thanks. I figured out the problem. The problem was everytime any user credential matches I was returning all users from that function and  I was giving user[0]. objects that was admin as claims . Thanks problem solved!